# Add tbody XML Element to table Element in XDcoument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

Want to add `<tbody>` element in `<table>` elements if missing on Xdcoument.

```
<table class="newtable" id="item_559_Table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" data-its-style="width:11.4624em; border-spacing:0;">
    <colgroup data-its-style="width:11.4624em; " />
    <tr>
        <td data-its-style="padding:0.2292em; vertical-align:top; ">
            <p data-its-style="">My dad cooks up a pot of chicken soup, and</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-its-style="padding:0.2292em; vertical-align:top; ">
            <p data-its-style="font-weight:normal; ">This cold means I can’t taste a thing today!</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Output should look like

```
<table class="newtable" id="item_559_Table1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" data-its-style="width:11.4624em; border-spacing:0;">
        <colgroup data-its-style="width:11.4624em; " />
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-its-style="padding:0.2292em; vertical-align:top; ">
                <p data-its-style="">My dad cooks up a pot of chicken soup, and</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-its-style="padding:0.2292em; vertical-align:top; ">
                <p data-its-style="font-weight:normal; ">This cold means I can’t taste a thing today!</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

**Not looking for XSLT solution.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to grab the children of `<table>`, then add them back they way you want them.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

var colgroup = doc.Root.Elements("colgroup");
var tr = doc.Root.Elements("tr");

// Add tr to tbody
var tbody = new XElement("tbody", tr);

// Replace the children of table with colgroup and tbody
doc.Root.ReplaceNodes(colgroup, tbody);
```